# How to increase space of temp in centos , As its 100% used

Tags: linux, centos, mysql

I have a server with Centos on and when I print `df -h` I get this output [OutPut of df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cduKC.jpg) the issue is that the temp folder is 100% used and I need to add more space to temp folder. I was wondering can any one help me as I have less experience with Linux and I have also tried codes like `lvresize` but it says insufficient space.

```
[root@ns1 ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup0-root
                  908G   13G  849G   2% /
tmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             243M   72M  158M  32% /boot
/dev/mapper/VolGroup0-tmp
                  976M  960M     0 100% /tmp
[root@ns1 ~]#
```

Output of `ls -l` is

```
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  2 21:49 3UocP8
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     0 Jan  3 21:57 e.mysql
drwx------. 2 root root 16384 Sep 11 03:03 lost+found
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 02:10 sess_02lt8blpha2hjd9fvjoimvp543
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:15 sess_049tsvhh6dgs554b9u2ra3av32
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 03:35 sess_070dnkje4lsk92abdgcngo24c4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:55 sess_0emeqaakt9153e87p8rsjqqcn2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:45 sess_0g7sboh1c24vcqcaguu2h6gjq0
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 22:40 sess_0jcmmfbs3qotopfb1nobb7m5d3
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:05 sess_0kf4tk9d5uod4fin73jheqa0r0
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:55 sess_0kuvoi5rs5i3f1dtbi0k3gqu91
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:25 sess_0pu6bsi95erqokftnroh6umar4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 22:35 sess_0tlh93o5nqm5hit7k58laojrp7
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:35 sess_12emje5ru2ndse53ke74k28u01
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 03:10 sess_157gr3hbfdb77mjneja83n3m47
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:05 sess_1880cq4gesliitso5t15ked254
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:05 sess_1cn44isoa9cmdeg6b8ak1k62e5
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:25 sess_1h1ksp9u19c2u98mqfj30d8212
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 23:55 sess_1h26v8r9afe1gtud3jlhf51g43
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:40 sess_1ja7dalbkpjv9bke8l9slnv746
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 05:45 sess_1qc2cfmnli5etkgnqbkdufs631
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:50 sess_1qq5ihlvsghndeubtpn61ba622
-rw-------  1 root root    37 Jan  3 03:40 sess_1s6nbtrd51cqhp0l0orbcmfu35
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 01:25 sess_1spaflggra7ec8hcvvkk15g7c2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 05:20 sess_22js4evme87t2es41fppum6eh3
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 01:50 sess_25rgiqm98a61eid67i7upccs94
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:50 sess_2a2rqqvts3j992u3f147ljk9h0
-rw-------  1 root root    37 Jan  3 21:59 sess_2cj34idrrn21bmvc40v9evm210
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 00:50 sess_2dsjs0fs6slcrfhip9vchmnth5
-rw-------  1 root root    37 Jan  3 04:00 sess_2loeqdefrfh3qonjui6a7hldq3
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:55 sess_2p1nvm52c6i4g3o849ukn5t434
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:50 sess_2tebauu4qg7kdt0klv0f638eh0
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 22:25 sess_335cqui2ja89lbad7nnlulsqa6
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 02:25 sess_39s38o2v79qjp8ig86qjjkibi3
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 01:35 sess_3m4a23ois3amfh4hupmpv0ijf4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 23:25 sess_3mb0s6gajerp3k9jsb0ot5q5b2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 04:10 sess_3vlq4716kpji41ov740i95ph07
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:55 sess_48gv9crkcv89k1dam4ke5r0k20
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 04:00 sess_48hcjoa08p2hrtltljc5rrsvd0
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 04:30 sess_4aa5vqslsnq9pu07v53hja5e81
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:30 sess_4j8tdcrb8dpeq37ssp45j0pl27
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:20 sess_4jhfgds7h2jio3dsfsavqure11
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:10 sess_4knainbs51meijfq22e04nagm1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:20 sess_4mfknqf1qlommjqho08mcodfq3
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 03:45 sess_4p5354gvt6e781gemphtlku0i2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:05 sess_52g2q6l3v46ke3ol8vrkm3hmh4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 01:05 sess_5d43ithmjbpa5afgkbbljd36q6
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:10 sess_5gcru5rtu36ftaepos8t55np72
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 23:20 sess_62d00rli602c8vl66c6cba0d26
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 00:40 sess_6dij04etr9vbdok7tnuqijkns1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:35 sess_6dtcs9tg4aka1et0tgoobdu6g1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 02:30 sess_6jabs7isqgfo5g7phaujk92gk7
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:10 sess_6lke3ibjb8ohcbtodisdg4p695
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:00 sess_6piv1d3cnvb9dmufpkecm544h2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 00:00 sess_6rki44erukp51af9aglb1ka2f2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:25 sess_6rt7l5n0dr7bfbk2as47f467s4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:50 sess_72k1knfboe45t0agphnocmct25
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:30 sess_75ctr6fuuk9lmoplh5jmqialh3
-rw-------  1 root root    37 Jan  3 03:45 sess_75ldhmccjd9ed2ggcoeek5jlk0
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 02:45 sess_77q5rrvle787sadj6cla8bvhh1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 22:55 sess_8764a6t51g8ot786j5ms1uqpb7
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 23:45 sess_89f9p6906mbv7siv3gd10vn1k1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:30 sess_89vp55p5rjj5mgc5n61inqsar5
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 04:40 sess_8c5197s69bn3in4f4urm68sf02
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:45 sess_8dmafmcac59ajq5c5ug5le3t17
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 01:15 sess_8h81uoa506tiho43i68ml70h74
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:40 sess_8lebbo46fk6v8hi43a6ql3r2s4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 00:05 sess_8qg3ld6356ncn1qmohh22t4vt6
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:15 sess_8rj4s26l43htgi12bckvs2ed27
-rw-------  1 root root    37 Jan  3 03:50 sess_91kkk3chr0u3r7ldebcuo57jj1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 05:55 sess_921t6a9tsorcr71shs8kl3sfr2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:20 sess_950qps7b7ggadbm0nhp6tuh4h2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:15 sess_9k0rg99r4lhedl4f8hj6k4tr11
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:40 sess_9lab77j959v5tqg92viah8r761
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 02:55 sess_a762areq9887r7q133dfl1t725
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 03:40 sess_aar3b6i7tfgs595fk33cid5ca2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:15 sess_abr4evd2d36mcbmj5idriamgt2
-rw-------  1 root root    37 Jan  3 21:57 sess_agj66945pu4os95mjtgot22926
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 01:45 sess_ahaeb54244lhjmpnbe8uc5jju5
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:40 sess_b06bi2uqajqig16huhgbum3dl2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 04:35 sess_bbeofn2c0ovk1sd09fvd2b7i73
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:00 sess_bn89dnktrir656ou3eq0flmak0
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 00:25 sess_cjm5kam9paihpdsmv0ah8qagb4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 04:45 sess_ctjfidldh8kuuokg53o7sp74i2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:00 sess_d7tpj8g6ufnlge3o0tup4eke03
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 22:15 sess_dd1ld71edav5pll63dt84bpao1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:50 sess_dj4keuqq16rms4i9vogppjg673
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:20 sess_dkjf0nmrhp3b7d2rodoq2obti0
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:10 sess_dmsgrs27euqgdtbm9g60ihj5m5
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 04:25 sess_e13os9rmjpudo6lus9b11qc9c0
-rw-------  1 root root    37 Jan  3 04:10 sess_e4obul8rm8fijuhda8brm53oo6
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 01:10 sess_e70crma9i53o397tctss19shv5
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:05 sess_e9g6fn5ls0qblddq4c2345uvr5
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:35 sess_ec46ir3tij41am3tp5dra95940
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 22:30 sess_ecib2kuhsuvjdkgt3uc0nq2mn1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 01:30 sess_eea3lhthjtvei62q76cnjr25o1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 01:00 sess_eigta62udv1fmq2nvqr39kjpr0
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 05:15 sess_ej9komlibdddkv2g7ekcv999l3
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:00 sess_euvkpt9i6sv0i5p1ictbbggcg2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:40 sess_faqmjgi9t3vh87e72c3f69qsj0
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 00:45 sess_ffbf5v5p3rs2mm8o0tuemkle01
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:45 sess_fh0uou2p2q6b885ovv8mljqm45
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 04:05 sess_ftl19us1tf27r3guu0rae7nqt1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:35 sess_ftlbbn6d7qevuaohni1k15gvm7
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:15 sess_g9jkbu391bmahpqlffh7jd04g0
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 22:20 sess_gq0quof1qb8dvrv136vjghf9o1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 00:55 sess_gv18q4oeopq8q62oarfdqg1m65
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 23:35 sess_h6aq86v2uv2v7jqn0dc6j0bsr2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:40 sess_hd07djg3i6nktoi1ve69tiqas4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:25 sess_hfcchujnt5tcrqd0lu9meiafb5
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:35 sess_hgncukivodp4jg6pt2a4ihas46
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 02:35 sess_hhjld0cjjed00b9c7nvr3onr55
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 03:15 sess_hk4ovo41ldjh6n81j6hlpee7h4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:30 sess_hm42e3ugncvdl6eqmnqtjkph84
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:30 sess_hqf3j7uj496o98o9rs30fagh57
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 00:20 sess_i50qfjbvgt7akeh04qo5k82pr5
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:30 sess_icdu1lm6ql23jer1lep417jk73
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:00 sess_il43g07t0mala3qg9qugb11gb0
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:35 sess_iqh5vhsoisgkhn6k7hsc4jdb73
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 02:40 sess_j1njq4g90cp6a68tkdnub7tdr1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 03:30 sess_j4nnjq1ta1sfpu45lfl9eceks7
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:05 sess_j5ge74f86p0kr15gpd0v0abec4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 23:05 sess_j605276gm02dcrqpu9bevgl9a2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 23:40 sess_j8re158ote9afqt8frqr6nfos2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:55 sess_jt1oho35rv7p1cqpsumqtjuhs6
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 03:25 sess_k482qnghmoghtm6utffuvumg15
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:45 sess_kaufo3m0osmnl10a500824qps1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 22:45 sess_kntt2di41o26b7ba7ft1ke0331
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:30 sess_krhihtubsc6gjarqbd93khllv1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 00:15 sess_kvjjhav30r91nr20ttb0j1ika6
-rw-------  1 root root    37 Jan  3 03:25 sess_l2p7grri5ucbdflknt1t99vqg5
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 02:50 sess_l36m2qon0id4qj4c9novp1h8m1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 01:55 sess_lbhl2al1spqqdou3vef5e828r5
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:45 sess_lq4lrj3hu8gt54fs9g6es6no72
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 23:10 sess_lrgeeadeqt4tvd3bunlq7js4d3
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 23:30 sess_m0b6bsknhlqaeqb6j4djuplft5
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:40 sess_m3j95qbg95qt4p8o2dp5abv7t6
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 22:50 sess_mt48f4agfho6214osvmomjn7g2
-rw-------  1 root root    37 Jan  3 03:35 sess_mvfc6lbd0rogv6d16lp3ipot57
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 23:15 sess_nq9mpvvb0v37ism961floj7cf6
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 02:05 sess_ns5m9eb3eimb3qfnublfenbb61
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:00 sess_o2olpf4a4blq5iov0d6c82dcp4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 03:50 sess_o441dpmd2a6i82hs8futtmb2e6
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 03:20 sess_o68pg76258riio057ra09djvm2
-rw-------  1 root root    37 Jan  3 04:05 sess_o76eaeccjsigopq8uh183av7o6
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 00:10 sess_o7oa8k5uajcgncs02hrfld0ia4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:25 sess_oaqd72ubrksau63bikdl2hu746
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:30 sess_oh24835rf6bokhkilaktfgjk77
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 04:15 sess_ohncb4c783r1uh9umj7ceaho16
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 23:50 sess_ooe9pljed6nbj2gvd6h7s46ds2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 02:20 sess_or5gitru0qr5bvodlrbu2t6md7
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 04:50 sess_ouvch03bqi9ts513ue57vrs635
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:15 sess_ovlr4dl8lsar4nogbeg49fu5u2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 02:15 sess_pg0e2u8fvckdda1opkr9oca276
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:35 sess_pl1qom0dek5njpf2chm97ji7m5
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 23:00 sess_q3beic17o0iu0r0sl5r3m1kql0
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:25 sess_q3tl9bka49lfm34has9k3atak1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 03:05 sess_q9h8gqbpo2sd6c87lijrho3td4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 04:55 sess_qgi14r7uv8qacvqkn36sij7r40
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:25 sess_qj947pkvcbbj9o6oarr7sa0mc1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:15 sess_ql2fdb0rjqdcorao9sur882kn6
-rw-------  1 root root    37 Jan  3 03:30 sess_qnqff2khldatlgenbg0he3gln3
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:20 sess_r66cel42emgorborp2a0616bi5
-rw-------  1 root root    37 Jan  3 03:55 sess_ranv99m912nheg310gf4odt5o0
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 05:25 sess_rs24ifc5cm9m326s4h1ssu0do6
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:10 sess_sfe57ljoe30ctgn1rerk9sn026
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:45 sess_sur6hsp66she4hbt42gemfbul2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:20 sess_tatemu4sce98prtugjd5rl4u37
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 04:35 sess_thsmkudiu58jb1e4ug3nhgi670
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 02:00 sess_tqt59dt7rf4v85esr7465qlbf3
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 00:30 sess_tr7v6jahf93nuqk50fbipg3c25
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:20 sess_u4nvcbfo4mnm2h7848308hv9u6
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:20 sess_u5c18ibphjb79tvaarcc8ug443
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:50 sess_u6c69cejn9pbb9vopauu90tfe2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 01:20 sess_ucc80kp9fabag7se17i1ipc8g2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 03:55 sess_ucfronu3ii701r4cdm06iu2tk4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 00:35 sess_ucfsc99nj3sntb0sumeocu2gd7
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 07:25 sess_udqbpmies8erhd46kc5lsn3sv0
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 01:40 sess_uphu25nlnjkcavvurptd2octb2
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:55 sess_uu3icb4kc6gp34eel7hs860n02
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:40 sess_v7cjmlclcbs3f8buqoug0lqdp4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 06:45 sess_v7ocbh5pb06fm1ll0bocdlj607
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 04:20 sess_v7ollcu44ak60c6vhmqo6rkf11
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  4 03:00 sess_vn9vitf39ihm2q848r5mljhfu1
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 05:10 sess_vr9ka9u0vtrv75rtc35p6l7kq6
drwx------  2 root root  4096 Jan  3 02:58 spamd-2310-init
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 20:11 tmp.0GI7SnoAcl
drwx------  5 root root  4096 Jan  3 22:00 tmp.eAf8ywXBlL
drwx------  3 root root  4096 Jan  3 04:10 tmp.fJtAldZyv7
drwx------  5 root root  4096 Jan  4 06:15 tmp.qvcJcczy0R
drwx------  3 root root  4096 Jan  2 19:10 tmp.TBUGbSyr8D
drwx------  5 root root  4096 Jan  3 22:05 tmp.tGQGKmQBq4
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  2 21:19 TOQwhJ
-rw-------  1 root root     0 Jan  3 02:59 tpOB3f
```

Comment: It would be much better to find out why `/tmp` is at 100% as by definition it is only for transient files such as session files or temporary database tables. Also, you have a `tmpfs` volume in memory which could be used but you still need to find out why it's filling.

Comment: You need to understand why this is happening before attempting to 'fix' it as, it will likely continue to happen. With that in mind, using site search at the top of the page and with terms like 'linux disk full' will surely be helpful.

Comment: How do i find that out ????

Comment: @Amani Don't post screenshots of a terminal. Copy the text from the terminal and use the code formatting option.

Comment: @SimonGreenwood The `tmpfs` is a different mountpoint so not very relevant to the question.

Comment: Find what out ?

Comment: how do i find out why /temp folder is taking 100% space ?? and also solve it ?

Comment: @Amani look in the folder and see what it there. Post the output of `ls -l`  (not a screenshot) if you want.

Comment: Use the search box above, like i suggested. You are not the first person by a long way to ask this question. It has been answered many times already.

Comment: @SimonGreenwood i have added the output of ls- l in the question i could not understand whats that :(

Comment: @user449299 i tried to find , but i am unable to get any solution !!

Comment: You're screwed then. I guess this is the problem with using control panel type installations they don;t give you the understanding of the underlying OS.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly /tmp folder will hold session files. you can navigate to /tmp folder and try to delete some unwanted files and session files.

```
cd /tmp
rm -f filename
```

If you think allocated partition size is not enough to handle server operation you can extend the partition if you have free space in your volumn group or on disk.

Comment: yes i did it and it works fine for 1 minute then again it starts increasing and then tmp folder gets full

Comment: @Amani : that's _EXACTLY_ why you have been told, here above, MULTIPLE TIMES, to SEARCH for the roots of your problems. You need to follow a "scientific" approach to solve your problem. You CANNOT follow a "random" or "your-own-defined" solution. It doesn't work this way. YOU NEED TO MAKE YOUR HOMEWORK. I'm sorry to appear a bit "rude". Sorry. Don't want to be so. But you have to understand that YOU HAVE TO STUDY by yourself. Your time is precious.... (so you don't want to search/study and prefer to ask). But ours... (guess what?)... is precious as well (at least!) :-) Good luck!

Comment: @Amani: BTW: you should be greatful to your ISP. Having a `/tmp` stored in a reserved/ad-hoc partition can be seen --in your particular case-- A PLUS!
Do you know what could have happened IF `/tmp` was NOT in a dedicated partition but, instead, stored as a common folder in `/`? I left to you the search/exercise for this last use-case :-)